# SQL query, three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So let's same I'm trying to find actors who are in two movies together (for the purpose of a degrees of separation page). I have databases as such (this is just some made up data):

actors

```
id     first_name     last_name    gender
17     brad           pitt         m
2      kevin          bacon        m
```

movies

```
id     name               year
20     benjamin button    2008
```

roles

```
a_id    m_id     role
17      20       Mr. Benjamin Button
```

So I want to return the names of the movies which both actors are in. I have the first and last names of two actors.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this to work. What I'm having trouble with, specifically, is the SELECT part

```
SELECT name FROM movies JOIN . . .
```

I'm starting with first_name and last_name values for each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must join twice:

```
SELECT m.name movie_name
FROM movies m join roles r1 on
   r1.m_id = m.id join actors a1 on
   r1.a_id = a1.id join roles r2 on
   r2.m_id = m.id join actors a2 on
   r2.a_id = a2.id
WHERE
  a1.first_name = 'brad' and a1.last_name = 'pitt' and
  a2.first_name = 'kevin' and a2.last_name = 'bacon'
```

Show all actor combinations per film:

```
SELECT m.name movie_name, a1.id actor1, a2.id actor2
FROM movies m join roles r1 on
   r1.m_id = m.id join actors a1 on
   r1.a_id = a1.id join roles r2 on
   r2.m_id = m.id join actors a2 on
   r2.a_id = a2.id
WHERE
  a1.id < a2.id
```

The `<` ensures that each combination is only reported once.

Answer (score 1):

```
select m.name,group_concat(concat_ws(' ',a.first_name,a.last_name) order by a.last_name) as actors
from actors as a
inner join roles as r on a.id = r.a_id
inner join movies as m on m.id = r.m_id
where r.a_id in (2,17)
group by r.m_id 
having count(r.a_id) = 2
order by m.name
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @FirstActorID int,
    @SecondActorID int;

select m.[name] 
from 
movies m
inner join [roles] r1 on r1.m_id = m.id and r1.a_id = @FirstActorID
inner join [roles] r2 on r2.m_id = m.id and r2.a_id = @SecondActorID